# ¿Qué significa "es sorprendentemente genuino" en esta oración?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

¿Tiene sentido la frase *es sorprendentement genuino* en la siguiente oración? La encontré en un texto sobre la educación estadísdica. No puedo enterderla en este contexto. ¿Puede darme esta oración traducida a inglés?

*Es sorprendentemente genuino a los estudiantes que los resúmenes de los datos (medias en este caso) puedan ir en una dirección en los datos agregados, pero puedan ir en dirección opuesta para cada subcategoría cuando son desagregados.*

Comment: Mala traducción.

Comment: una oracion con la palabra genuino plis

Answer (score 5):

Parece una traducción directo del frase "genuine surprise" en Ingles.

> It was a genuine surprise to the students that the data (averages in this case) can go in one direction in aggregate, but can go in the opposite direction for each subcategory when separated.

In English I have seen this phrase often used for summaries of educational activity.  It gives extra emphases to the fact the students did not know it before.

Answer (score 2):

Estoy de acuerdo con la respuesta de Meep, lo que nos lleva a buscar una mejor traducción al español:

> Fue una verdadera sorpresa para los estudiantes que los datos (en este caso los promedios) puedan ir en un sentido pero vayan en sentido opuesto para cada subcategoría cuando éstas se toman por separado.

Comment: Yo intentaría conservar las palabaras agregados/desagregados que es un término técnico en estadística.

Comment: Qudaría: Fue una verdadera sorpresa para los estudiantes que los datos (en este caso los promedios) puedan ir en un sentido en los datos agregados, pero vayan en sentido opuesto para cada subcategoría cuando son desagregados.

Comment: En lugar de "fue" diría "es"

Answer (score 0):

No tiene sentido. Parece que fuera una mala traducción.

Answer (score 0):

"sorprendentemente genuino" es una pésima traducción qeu confunde adjetivo y adverbio, lo correcto era "genuinamente sorprendente" (truly surprising); aunque la repetición "mente/mente" suena algo dura, y el resto tampoco está bien traducido.

Algunas alternativas (de paso se trata de la [paradoja de Simpson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox), ¿no?)

> Resulta muy sorprendente para  los
>   estudiantes que un resumen de los datos (en este caso la media) pueda
>   ir en un sentido si se toman los datos agrupados, pero van en sentido
>   opuesto para cada subgrupo cuando se toman por separado.
>
> Causa genuina sorpresa a los estudiantes 
>   que un resumen de los datos (en este caso la media) pueda
>   ir en un sentido cuando se toman los datos agrupados, pero van en sentido
>   opuesto para cada subgrupo cuando se toman por separado.